# React Native BackgroundTimer API Fetch respons more than once

Tags: react-native

I am new on React Native, somethings could be wrong in my code.

I want to check API every 10-sec. The code should be okay but I don't understand why it responds more than once every time when the Backgroundtimer calls.

```
const App = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://192.168.2.131/api/QChatTrakan?templateNo=22')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, [reflesh]);


  BackgroundTimer.runBackgroundTimer(() => { 
    fetch('http://192.168.2.131/api/QChatTrakan?templateNo=22')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => setData(json))
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  console.log(data);
  }, 
  10000);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGnXE.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the below code for call function or fetch API every 10 seconds.

```
const callAPi = () => {
console.log('callAPi initial',new Date().toLocaleString())
setInterval(() => {
  console.log('callAPi',new Date().toLocaleString())
},10000)}

useEffect(() => {
  callAPi()
}, [])
```

[image: Image for log]